# SqlSave Error: Unable to append to table

Tags: sql, r, append, primary-key

Code:

```
sqlSave(SQL,data.frame(df),tablename='Data',append = TRUE,rownames = FALSE)
```

The table in which I am trying to insert the data has a primary key which is auto-increment. My table has a total of 5 columns including the primary key. In my data frame, I have 4 columns because I don't want to insert the PK myself. However, when I run the command, I get the following error:

*Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("BId", "name", "Set",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent*

Also, when I insert the Primary key in the dataframe by myself, it still doesn't work.

*Error in sqlSave(SQL, data.frame(df), tablename = "Data",  : 
  unable to append to table ‘Data’*

Comment: That error does not have to do with `sqlSave`. What is content of `df`? Run `str(data.frame(df))`as you may have nested lists in column. Show df's origin.

Comment: No nested lists in column. Its a df created using another table in database which I am trying to append a different table.

Comment: Also, did a lot of research but no post had solutions where Sqlsave is use to append a dataframe which has a PK invloved. It works well for a table with no PK

Comment: What backend database are you using RODBC on? Oracle? SQL Server? DB2? MS Access? Are you allowed to create temp tables?

Comment: SQL Server. I don't want to create tables but append data.

Comment: Temp tables will just be temporary overwritten each time to append to final to align PKs.

Answer (score 0):

have a try `safer = FALSE`

the defination of sqlSave

```
if (!append) {
    if (safer) 
        stop("table ", sQuote(tablename), " already exists")
        ......
    }
    ......
if (safer) 
    stop("unable to append to table ", sQuote(tablename))
```

Comment: this will drop the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use verbose argument to get the actual database error.

```
sqlsave(con, df, verbose = T)
```